# Scala compiler not able to deduce implicit view

Tags: scala, types, playframework

The call to `foo` produce the compiler error below, if I do not explicitly instantiate a type-specific version of the `formatFromString` function. However, in the `bar` case, the compiler is able to deduce the correct implicit parameter.

Why?

```
import play.api.libs.json.{Reads, Writes, Json}

case class Person(name: String, age: Int)

object Person { implicit val jsonFormat = Json.format[Person] }

def foo[T](input: String)(implicit fromS: String => T): T = fromS("")

def bar[T](input: T)(implicit toS: T => String): String = ""

implicit def formatFromString[T : Reads](s: String): T = Json.parse(s).validate[T].get

implicit def formatToString[T : Writes](x: T): String = Json.toJson(x).toString

// If I uncomment this line, everything works ...
// implicit val personFromString = formatFromString[Person] _

foo[Person]("")
bar(Person("Peter", 1234))
```

Compiler error:

> Error:(18, 13) No implicit view available from String => Person.
>       fooPerson
>                  ^

Comment: try to move reads and writes under Person companion object?

Comment: I tried moving the implicit methods between the Person companion and foo, but that did not change anything. Is that what you meant?